# Convert log into json and store it into memory

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, logging

I have this snippet of code which converts a user-selected log file into json and stores it to a file (using pandas' to_json function).

```
import pandas as pd

with open(self.get_logfile_path()) as log_file:
     log_file = log_file.read().splitlines()


df = pd.DataFrame(log_file)

df.to_json(r'C:\Users\xx\Downloads\abc.json')
```

My question is, how do I store the converted json file into memory temporarily (with every key being the start of a newline), instead of outputting it into some directory? I'm using Python 3.8.1.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the file in memory _permanently_?

Comment: store it temporarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Convert dataframe "df" to dictionary
df_dict = df.to_dict()

#Store the dictionary into a json string variable in memory
df_json = json.dumps(df_dict)

#Print the json contents
print(df_json)
```